# Reading a serial port in ruby using winddows

Tags: ruby, serial-port, arduino-uno

I have some problem because I don't know how you can put in which COM(serial port) is my arduino in next code:

```
require 'serialport'

sp = SerialPort.new "/dev/**PATH_TO_YOUR_DEVICE**", 9600

case ARGV[0]
when 1
  sp.write 1
when 0
  sp.write 0
end
```

How do you write that PATH?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some investigation I found my own answer and I want to share with you guys because it was hard find it.

```
parameters = {
    "baud"=>9600,
    "data_bits"=>8,
    "stop_bits"=>1,
    "parity"=>SerialPort::NONE }
comm_port = 3
sp = SerialPort.new(comm_port, parameters)
```

Probably it will be useful for someone.